# How apply filter after the text been sanitized(AngularJS)

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, chat

So, what do i have:

- Text that contains smiles like `:)` `:(` `:\`
- A filter that replace smiles with `img` tag
- `DIV` with `{{ message | smiles }}`

Like you know, the `{{}}` converts all html tags to html entities.

So i get: `Message that contains smile <img src="/smile.gif">`

I tried to use `ng-bind-html` and `$sanitize`, but it's do not sanitaize "good" html tags like `<b>`, `<a>`, etc...

I want to apply my `smiles` filter AFTER that `message` variable be sanitized. And i dont know how to do that.

EDIT1:

`message` variable contains "`here message with smiles :) :( :\`"

Filter that converts 'smiles' to `img` tag:

```
angular.module('my.filters', [])
.filter('smiles', function () {
  return function (input) {
    return input.replace(/:\)/gi, '<img src="/images/smile.gif">');
  }
});
```

The `DIV` element:

```
<div>{{ message | smiles}}</div>
```

When it's rendered i get:

`here message with smiles <img src="/images/smile.gif">`

and not `here message with smiles` [image]

Comment: what do you **expect** to happen?

Comment: I expect to get ESCAPED message, only with `img` tag for smile. I dont want to let users to use any html tags, so i need to apply `smiles` filter AFTER the angular escapes the message

Comment: can you enclose some code? that would make things a-lot easier.

Answer (score 0):

are you sure you're injecting ngSanitize in your module and using ng-bind-html?

here's a working example: http://plnkr.co/edit/IEovofjHDMleLZlb9AMJ?p=preview

Comment: `ngSinitize` and `ng-bind-html` doesn't help here, coz `ng-bind-html` don't remove html tags. I dont want to allow to users use of any html tags. So i need apply filter AFTER that message been sanitized(all html\script tags removed)

Comment: so it seems that your question is not correctly formed. isn't something you would do in your filter? you'd bind user input to an ng-model and print out the filtered model wherever you need it. in your filter you can then strip all the tags if you don't want them, just matter of playing a bit with regexes